# how to get specific objects/keys in the returned json format string

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

Do you know how to get the first 3 items in my json display.
Currently it displays as whole string.
I need to break the items/object and display only what is needed.

Here's my code to loop and display my record.

```
<tr v-for="(list) in myData" v-bind:key="list.email">
     <td class="right">
        <pre id="json"><code>{{ list.detailsData }}</code></pre>
     </td>        
</tr>
```

My display in my page is here per rows:

```
{
  "ActionsEnabled": true,
  "AlarmActions": [
    "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:334477424785:postgres"
  ],
  "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-west-2:334477424786:alarm:billing-comples-org-meta-test-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm",
  "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2021-07-13T04:00:39.137000+00:00",
  "AlarmName": "billing-comples-net-metadata-test-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm",
  "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
  "Dimensions": [
    {
      "Name": "TableName",
      "Value": "billing-comples-net-metadata-test1"
    }
  ],
  "EvaluationPeriods": 5,
  "InsufficientDataActions": [],
  "MetricName": "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits",
  "Namespace": "AWS/DynamoDB",
  "OKActions": [],
  "Period": 120,
  "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [0.5 (13/08/21 04:00:00)] was not greater than or equal to the threshold (340.0).",
  "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2021-07-13T04:04:36.086+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2021-07-13T04:00:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Sum\",\"period\":60,\"recentDatapoints\":[0.5],\"threshold\":240.0,\"evaluatedDatapoints\":[{\"timestamp\":\"2021-07-13T04:00:00.000+0000\",\"sampleCount\":1.0,\"value\":0.5}]}",
  "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2021-07-13T05:04:36.092000+00:00",
  "StateValue": "OK",
  "Statistic": "Sum",
  "Threshold": 240
}


{
  "ActionsEnabled": true,
  "AlarmActions": [
    "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:334477424785:postgres"
  ],
  "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-2:334477424785:alarm:platform-integrations-definitions-demo-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm",
  "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-05-14T22:04:09.285000+00:00",
  "AlarmName": "platform-definitions-demo-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm",
  "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
  "Dimensions": [
    {
      "Name": "TableName",
      "Value": "platform-integrations-definitions-demo"
    }
  ],
  "EvaluationPeriods": 5,
  "InsufficientDataActions": [],
  "MetricName": "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits",
  "Namespace": "AWS/DynamoDB",
  "OKActions": [],
  "Period": 60,
  "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 5 datapoints were not greater than or equal to the threshold (240.0). The most recent datapoints which not crossed the threshold: [0.0 (14/05/19 22:02:00), 0.0 (14/05/19 22:01:00), 0.0 (14/05/19 22:00:00), 0.0 (14/05/19 21:59:00), 0.0 (14/05/19 21:58:00)].",
  "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-05-14T22:06:52.950+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-05-14T21:58:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Sum\",\"period\":60,\"recentDatapoints\":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],\"threshold\":240.0}",
  "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-05-14T22:06:52.952000+00:00",
  "StateValue": "OK",
  "Statistic": "Sum",
  "Threshold": 240
}
```

Basically some of them I don't need to display or need to hide.
Example are
"AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp":
"Period": 60,
"StateReason":

I don't need to display the keys of "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp" , "Period" and "StateReason"

Would there be ways how to achieve it? Any tips , advice, and solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To render specific fields, refer to them by name, using dot notation on the object. For example, to display `Statistic` and `Threshold`, do: `{{ list.detailsData.Statistic }}` and `{{ list.detailsData.Threshold }}`. You pick the fields to show by explicitly referencing them in the template.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really are trying to dump the entire `detailsData` object while excluding specific fields, you could pass the object to a method that returns a new object without those fields, or use a computed prop to pre-compute the end result to display.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the advice. 
One last thing , what if i want to get the first 3 objects without specifying by name? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

*Do you know how to get the first 3 items in my json display ?* - Yes, To achieve this you can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method of JavaScript.

```
<tr v-for="list in myData.slice(0,3)" v-bind:key="list.email">
```

And to render specific fields, You can access them using dot notation on the object.

```
Ex: {{ list.detailsData.ComparisonOperator }}
```